# how to combine Two recordset data to one recordset in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am calling two “stored procedures” using different database connection. I used two separate record sets in page but I required combining both in one record set along with sorting also required.

Ex: two records set Rs1, Rs2

### Rs1 data

Emp_code Name  Grade

001      Bcd    A

004  Abc    C

### Rs2 data

Emp_code    Name    Grade

002 Xyz A

005 Zxy B

### But I required to displaying following table with sorting (emp_code asc, name asc, grade asc)

Emp_code    Name    Grade

001 Bcd A

002 Xyz A

004 Abc C

005 Zxy B

click this link it display properly

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNLOn.jpg

Comment: Would it not be easier combining them before returning the recordsets, if it's SQL Server you could use Linked Servers to query both sources and combine them using a `UNION` then return the one recordset as normal.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a table, loop through recordset 1 to create some rows, loop through recordset 2 to create some more, then use (client side) Javascript to order the table - see here http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Create a third recordset and paste the rows from RS1 and Rs2 into that new one:

```vbs
set newRs = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")

for each fld in Rs1.fields
    newRs.fields.append fld
next

newRs.open

' fill data from Rs1
do while not rs1.eof
    for each fld in Rs1.Fields
        newRs(fld.name).value = fld.value
    next
    newRs.update

    rs1.movenext
loop

' fill data from Rs2
do while not rs2.eof
    for each fld in Rs2.Fields
        newRs(fld.name).value = fld.value
    next
    newRs.update

    rs2.movenext
loop

newRs.Sort = "emp_code asc, name asc, grade asc"
```

Comment: Thank you for given solution. I will try and update you if any queries